# How can you safely compare a 32-bit integer with 64-bit integer in C++ and how signed integer is compared internally?

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

The question actually comes from this snippet

```
 int a = -1;
 unsigned int c=1;
 long long b = c<<31;

 printf("%d %lld %d\n",a,b,a>b);
```

I tested it on Linux gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3), the result is:
-1 2147483648 0

Actually I cannot understand the result. I my opinion, when you do a>b, a is converted to long long first, so a is 0000...01111...1(32 zeros + 32 ones), b is 000..01000...00 (32 zeros + one + 31 zeros), then a should be bigger than b.

Am I missing something of integer comparison in C++?

Comment: No, conversion between signed types doesn't work like this. -1 is converted to -1, not to some large positive value.

Answer (score 0):

Before the comparison the value of `a` is converted to a `long long` which still has the value -1.

Comment: so I guess in C++, unsigned value is bitwise comparison. signed type is not. Then, how does it do the comparison for signed type? Convert it to complement and do bitwise comparison?

Comment: There is no bitwise comparison. Numbers are compared as numbers.

Comment: @n.m. how does it do value comparison internally in machine though? It has to do binary comparison in some degree eventually right?

Comment: It may do a binary comparison, or it may not. It is not even guaranteed that signed types are represented in binary (such guarantee only exists for unsigned types). Anyway, even if it does binary comparison, what difference does it make? It compares numbers as numbers, that's all that matters. If you are specifically interested in bitwise comparison, use a data type suitable for such operation (such as `unsigned int`).

Comment: @n.m: Peiti Peter Li explicitly requested how the comparison is done inside the machine. There is no reason not to answer their question. Not everybody wants to restrict their knowledge to the imaginary computing model inside the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: *The* machine relevant to [tag:c] is the abstract machine defined in the C standard.

Comment: @n.m.: Do you believe that was what they were asking about?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I try to provide answers and comments that would benefit the original poster *and* other readers that come to this site. If I don't always  manage to answer the exact question being asked, well, sorry about that.

Comment: @PeitiPeterLi: (Corrected to omit unneeded overflow check.) Comparison of numbers with n bits inside a machine is essentially done as if the numbers had n+1 bits. For two”s complement integers, it is as if the numbers were sign-extended to n+1 bits (so overflow cannot occur), then subtracted to produce a result with n+1 bits, then tested to see whether the result is negative (less than), zero (equal), or positive (greater than). Usually, this is documented in terms of a carry/borrow bit instead of n+1 bits, but the mathematics is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct.  a is a signed int, so -1 is negative.  b is a signed long long; it has a positive sign.  Of course a negative number is not greater than a positive.

If you wanted (for some reason!) to show a as an unsigned long long, this would do it:

printf("%ull %lld %d\n",a,b,a>b);

If you wanted to force it into an unsigned long long:

unsigned long long a=ax;

And if you wanted to compare it to b, and thereby treat it as an unsigned long long w/o declaring it as such:

printf("%d %lld %d\n",a,b, a > (unsigned long long) b);